# Concurrent poll issue in Python

Tags: python, rabbitmq

This problem has been bothering me for a few days now. I am running multiple consumers using RabbitMQ by opening multiple threads and I got the error below.

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 905, in queue_declare
    None, replies)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 1141, in _rpc
    self._wait_on_response(method_frame))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 1162, in _send_method
    self.connection.process_data_events()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 240, in process_data_events
    if self._handle_read():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 347, in _handle_read
    if self._read_poller.ready():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 43, in inner
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 85, in ready
    events = self.poller.poll(self.poll_timeout)
RuntimeError: concurrent poll() invocation
```

A lot of Googling leads me to [Issue 8865](http://bugs.python.org/issue8865) which describes how select.poll() function can not be called concurrently.
And this bug can be triggered by the following script consistently:

```
import os
import select
import threading
import time


p = select.poll()
rfds = []
r, w = os.pipe()


for i in range(1000):
    fd = os.dup(r)
    rfds.append(fd)
    p.register(fd, select.POLLIN)

def resize_ufds_array():
    time.sleep(0.5)

    # trigger ufds array reallocation
    for fd in rfds:
        p.unregister(fd)
    p.register(w, select.POLLOUT)
    p.poll()

    # and make the call to poll() from the main thread return
    os.write(w, b'hello')

t = threading.Thread(target=resize_ufds_array)
t.start()
p.poll()
```

I find this script can not trigger the bug on my local Python 2.7.8 installed from Window MSI because select.poll is removed. However, in my prod environment it's Ubuntu 14.04 and I tried install Python 2.7.6-2.7.9 from source code and they all have this bug. Any idea how to fix this issue on Ubuntu? There is a python fix for this issue for 2.7 versions [here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/a4091c1de27a) But somehow after I applied the patch the script is still showing the error.